# PutObject error: in uploading a file to AWS S3 using aws-cpp-sdk

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a file in c++ to upload an avi file to AWS S3 storage.
The program is as follow.

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/core/utils/HashingUtils.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace Aws::S3::Model;
using namespace std;
using namespace Aws::Utils;

static const char* KEY = "test.avi";
static const char* BUCKET = "testnmn";

int main()
{
    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    Aws::InitAPI(options);   

    const Aws::String bucket_name = BUCKET;
    const Aws::String key_name = KEY;
    const Aws::String dir_name = "/home/Softwares/Projects/S3upload/build";

    std::cout << "Uploading " << key_name << " to S3 bucket: " <<
        bucket_name << std::endl;

    Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client;

    Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest object_request;
    object_request.WithBucket(bucket_name).WithKey(key_name);

    auto input_data = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::FStream>(key_name.c_str(), dir_name.c_str(), std::ios_base::in);

    object_request.SetBody(input_data);

    auto put_object_outcome = s3_client.PutObject(object_request);

    if(put_object_outcome.IsSuccess()) {
        std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
         std::cout << "PutObject error: " <<
             put_object_outcome.GetError().GetExceptionName() << " " <<
             put_object_outcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
    }

    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);

    return 0;  
}
```

When I run the exe file, I have error as

```
Uploading test.avi to S3 bucket: testnmn
PutObject error: PermanentRedirect Unable to parse ExceptionName: PermanentRedirect Message: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

What could be wrong with that error?

Thanks

Comment: Did you solved this problem? If you have done, could you share how to solve it, please?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Bucket that you are trying to access has been created in a different region (than default, which I believe is us-east-1) & hence the endpoint does not match.

You can set the region using the ClientConfiguration:

```
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration myConf;
myConf.region = Aws::Region::US_WEST_2;
Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(myConf);
```